# How to create test automation reports in flutter?

Tags: flutter-test

I am new to flutter and my team is expecting me to automate mobile app using Flutter Driver(deprecated) / Integration Tests. They want reporting the way it is present in Selenium WebDriver which uses Extent Report for failed and passed test case with each test step.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Flutter driver is not deprecated